# How to install Python module dependencies from my RPM?

Tags: centos, python, rpm, packaging

I have an application that I am packaging as an RPM and installing on CentOS 7. When I install the RPM I want it to install some compiled binaries as well as some Python modules with their dependencies.

My Python modules require a newer version of Python than is provided by CentOS, so I will be installing the modules in a Python altinstall under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. This means I can't use CentOS-provided RPMs since they install under `/usr/lib`. I can easily install the modules under `/usr/local/lib` using `pip`.

Is there a way to package my application such that:

- I can install my application from an RPM.
- My Python modules get installed under `/usr/local/lib` when the application is installed.
- Any Python dependencies also get installed.
- I avoid maintaining RPM packages for the Python dependencies.

Is there a convention for this kind of thing? Or are there maybe some examples? I didn't see anything directly relevant in [Fedora's Python Packaging documentation](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python).

The options I have considered are:

1. Bundle my application, Python modules, and all Python dependencies into one RPM.

   I don't like this option because I would not be able to update individual dependencies on the client system without upgrading my entire application to a new version.
2. Create individual RPMs for my application, my Python modules, and third-party dependencies.

   I don't like this option because I would have to maintain RPMs for every single third-party module in my dependency tree.
3. Call `pip` from within my RPM.

   I don't like this option because RPM would not be able to track the changes that `pip` makes, and I would not be able to determine whether I can safely remove third-party Python modules when removing the RPM.

Answer (score 0):

Using Software Collections you can have new version of modules on old system or old modules on new system. See:
http://www.softwarecollection.org/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this doesn't resolve my core problem: how to install Python module dependencies from my RPM?